# Replacing .Open with .Add

Tags: excel, vba

Changed hotkey macro from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and changed '**Open**' to '**Add**' because '**Open**' causes macro to stop after the new workbook opens. Was told '**Add**' wouldn't do that. However, since the desired filespec is contained in a cell, apparently '**Add**' doesn't like the same argument '**Open**' had accepted.

Examples

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=(sheets(1).Range("w6").TEXT) - - Works

Workbooks.Add filename:=(sheets(1).Range("w6").TEXT)  - - Doesn't work
```

VB says "**Named argument not found**".

Can't find Add in Walkenbach's book for context or help.

Need proper context/argument for '**Add**'.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim thisWb As Workbook, newWb As Workbook

    Set thisWb = ThisWorkbook

    Set newWb = Workbooks.Add(thisWb.Sheets(1).Range("W6").Value)
End Sub
```

To understand how it work's see the Excel Help :). You can do that by pressing the magic key <kbd>F1</kbd>

[image]